# afterEach happening before it

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to use protractor to make e2e tests for one of our pages.
The pages are run in an iframe of a surrounding system.

So to be able to test my page I have to do all the things before "it ('Overview opened...". I'm not saying I have to do them in the way I have done. If there is a better way, please tell me.

Now my problem is that "errandClose is run before the tests in "Overview opened".
Have I done something wrong or misunderstood how protractor works.

```
describe('toplevel test', function() {
    var login = new loginPage();
    var role = new roleSelectionPage();
    var errand = new overViewAndErrand(login.getBaseUrl());

    beforeEach(function() {
        login.getPage(); //Goes to login page and logs in
    });

    it('should log in', function () {

        expect(element(by.model("therole")).isDisplayed());

        describe('Select role', function() {

            beforeEach(function () {
                role.selectRole(); //Selects role on page after login and ends up at next page
            });


            it('Role selected', function() {
                expect(element(by.css('a[href*="/OverviewNext"]')) !== undefined);

                describe('Open overview', function() {
                    beforeAll(function() {
                        errand.open('name of errand'); //Selects errand and clicks on button, iframe i opened
                    });

                    afterEach(function() {
                        errand.close(); // Leaves the iframe and clicks on remove errand
                    });

                    it ('Overview opened', function() {

                        describe('Test form', function() {
                            browser.sleep(5000); 
                            it ('test', function() {
                                browser.sleep(500);
                                element(by.model("modelvalue")).sendKeys('Ture Trana').then(function() {console.log('Ture Trana')});                                                             
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

As a response to the flat question.

How I would like to be able to run my tests is something like this

```
login.getPage();

role.select('role1');

errand.create();

begin
    test 1
     ...
    test n
end

errand.save();

role.select(role 2);

errand.open(previous errand);

begin
    test 1
     ...
    test n
end

login.logout();
```

Where all the selectRole, createErrand, openErrand involves going to at least one page and clicking on some buttons and selecting in lists.

Comment: Flat is usually better and easier than nested. Do you really have to nest it and describes that much?

Comment: To be honest I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't nest describe() within it().

You should close this test before you start a new one
Example:  This should be closed before you start a new describe.

```
it('Role selected', function() {
            expect(element(by.css('a[href*="/OverviewNext"]')) !== undefined);
```

Comment: It turned into this nested thing since my first version didn't work at all. This almost works. See the added pseudo code below my first codeblock. The login and role selection parts really aren't something I need to test. That part should be done by those making the surrounding system. But to get to "my" page all those other parts need to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with nested describes, that works for me.

```
    describe('overview page', () => {
      let hostUrl = configMock[0].response.data.URL;

      beforeAll(() => {
        //do magic
      });

      describe('all statement cards', () => {
        beforeAll(() => {
          browser.get(`${hostUrl}/z/y/1/g`);
          browser.waitForAngular();
        });

        describe('Campaign overview', () => {
          beforeEach(() => {
            //before each magic
          });
          it('has correct data for Delivered', () => {
            expect(delivered.getText()).toEqual('1.6k');
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

Starting from this, I think you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: After some more fiddling(spelling?) around I have a flat version that seems to work. Now all I have to do is make it do all the tests needed. Thanxs everyone for turning my head in the right direction.

Comment: you could also have nested structures, but you will have to pay close atention to whatever you want to do, specially if you want to play around with before/after hooks inside the nested groups ;)